# Bash not executing correctly with '@' character

Tags: linux, bash, shell, azure-devops

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
host=$1
conector=$2
configs='connector.class: io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector, tasks.max: 1'

echo "{ name: $conector,  config: { $configs } }" > payload.json
curl -v $host/connectors -d @payload.json -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

And I can execute in this way:

```
 bash create.sh http://10.0.0.78:8083 test
```

If I execute locally in my machine I got the following result:

```
$ bash create.sh http://10.0.0.78:8083 test
+ host=http://10.0.0.78:8083
+ conector=test
+ configs='connector.class: io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector, tasks.max: 1'
+ echo '{ name: test,  config: { connector.class: io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector, tasks.max: 1 } }'
+ curl -v http://10.0.0.78:8083/connectors -d @payload.json -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
*   Trying 10.0.0.78:8083...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:08 --:--:--     0
```

This ok for me, the server doesn't respond but the "curl -v ... " is correct. Now I tried to execute in Linux Server the same command, and got the following:

```
+ host=http://10.8.0.78:8083
+ conector=test
+ configs='connector.class: io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector, tasks.max: 1'
+ echo '{ name: test,  config: { connector.class: io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector, tasks.max: 1 } }'
+ curl -v http://10.8.0.78:***@payload.json -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
*   Trying 10.8.0.78...
* TCP_NODELAY set
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
```

Note the curl created by the bash in server:

```
curl -v http://10.8.0.78:***@payload.json
```

Don't make sense, this URL doesn't exist. I noted this occurs because of '@' character, bash in server is interpreting this character, I don't know why.

**Edit 1**

Return from command: `LC_ALL=C cat -v create.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
host=$1
conector=$2
configs='connector.class: io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector, tasks.max: 1'

echo "{ name: $conector,  config: { $configs } }" > payload.json
curl -v $host/connectors -d @payload.json -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

**Edit 2**
I'm using azuredevops to execute script:

```
jobs:
  - job: Deploy
    pool: ${{parameters.agent}}
    displayName: Deploy
    steps:
      - checkout: templates
      - script: "bash create.sh $(KAFKACONNECT_URL) ${{parameters.conector}} \"${{parameters.configs}}\""
```

I don't know if this can be the reason for the problem.

**Problem Solved**

In fact, the `"http://10.8.0.78:***@payload.json"` is not a problem, the script is executing very well and the URL is correct, but for some reason, AzureDevops Output Console is hidding it instead of show complete URL (as I expected). I enabled `"--trace"` in curl and saw that curl is posting my payload and URL as I expected. So, the solution is just to accept it, AzureDevops Console is confusing.

Comment: `@` should not cause this; I suspect the problem is happening for some other reason. Are you sure the script file got transferred to the Linux server correctly? You can check the script for weird/nonprinting/garbled characters with `LC_ALL=C cat -v yourscript.sh`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I edited my post with return that I got with command LC_ALL

Comment: It's preferably better to [edit your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67232630/bash-insert-before-character) instead of starting new ones. || From what you have presented it should have worked. The conclusion is, there is something you do now know or are not aware of _about the environment_ that is causing that behavior. `o execute in Linux Server` In what "linux server"? What is on that "linux server"? `Return from command` Did you execute the command _in the same environment_ you are getting the confusing behavior? Please test in `- script: "cat -v script.sh"`

Comment: "Linux Server" is a Centos Distro running as an Agent AzureDevops. I executed the "cat -v script.sh" and return was the same that "LC_ALL=C cat -v yourscript.sh"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for some reason, AzureDevops Output Console is hidding it instead of show complete URL

The Azure console incorrectly believes that `http://10.0.0.78:8083/connectors -d @payload.json` is a URL of the form `http://user:password@host.domain` and therefore is replacing what it thinks is a password (`8083/connectors -d` ) with `***`.

Comment: Thanks for explain it, really confused but it's ok, I can live with this. Rsrsrsrs

Comment: Hi @RonaldoLanhellas, what about this issue? If the answer help you, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.